# Incremental progress on nested stored procedure (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have three Postgres stored procedures that are being ran sequentially (i.e. SP1 will call SP2 which then calls SP3). while proc'ing these nested stored procedures I noticed that I do not see the results from SP1 only until the last stored procedure has completed (SP3).

Is there a way to have the results of these procedures be produced at the time of execution rather than waiting for all of them to be complete?

Thanks!

Some code for reference:

```
create or replace procedure sp1()
as $$

declare

begin
    
    drop table if exists seq_test;
    create table seq_test (
        step        varchar,
        status      varchar,
        time_log    timestamp not null default now()
    );
    
    insert into seq_test values ('1','running','now');
    raise notice 'step 1 beginning';
    
    -- does something

    insert into seq_test values ('1','complete','now');
    raise notice 'step 1 complete';
    
    call sp2(); 
        
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

--------------

create or replace procedure sp2()
as $$

declare

begin
    
    insert into seq_test values ('2','running','now');
    raise notice 'step 2 beginning';
    
    -- does something else

    insert into seq_test values ('2','complete','now');
    raise notice 'step 2 complete';
    
    call sp3(); 

end;
$$
language plpgsql;

--------------

create or replace procedure sp3()
as $$

declare

begin
    
    insert into seq_test values ('3','running','now');
    raise notice 'step 3 beginning';
    
    -- does something else

    insert into seq_test values ('3','complete','now');
    raise notice 'step 3 complete';
        
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

--------------------------------------------------

call sp1();
```

In the above script, if hypothetically each SP takes 1 minute to complete, despite records being inserted into **seq_test** throughout the entire 3 minute runtime I wont actually be able to observe these records until every SP has completed.

Comment: I assume you run a query in another session to see the results. Correct you cannot see them and this is **intentional by design** as a consequence of Postgres being a [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/mvcc.html) system. In this setup sp1 establishes a [transaction](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-transaction/) which is effective until it ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the results, because data modifications only become visible when the transaction that made them has ended. This is guaranteed by the default `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation level, and there is no way in PostgreSQL to get “dirty reads”.

By default, `CALL sp1()` will run in a single transaction, which explains what you observe.

You can change that behavior by explicitly calling `COMMIT AND CHAIN` inside your stored procedures. That will commit the work up to this point and start a new transaction. But consider the consequences: if execution encounters an error, the transaction will be rolled back (undone). A `COMMIT` in the middle of your procedure can then result in only part of the work being done. This may be exactly what you need, but often it is undesirable.